# How come the Vim cursor leaves one character at the end of the line?

Tags: cursor

It sounds like a bit of a silly question, but I couldn't find any answers. I've noticed that in the command mode, the Vim cursor doesn't go until the complete end of the line and stops at the last character. Why does it do this? And is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: It may feel unusual at first, but I don't mind anymore. Why would you like to move it behind the last character, is there some usecase broken?

Comment: No, that's not the case at all. I was just curious because sometimes I want to enter insert mode at the end of the line but found it odd that I was having to move one space to the right every time I did that. But you're right, I am getting used to it.

Comment: @Seankala You can actually use <kbd>A</kbd> (shift + a) to start inserting at the end of the line (from anywhere on the line).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does it do this?

Cursor is on a character that has actual place in a buffer. After the last character there is no actual place to put cursor on. Unless you use virtual place.

> And is there a way to change this behavior?

To make it have one more character after the end of line use `virtualedit` option:

```
set virtualedit+=onemore
```

PS, some external plugins might become broken if you set it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this seemed like such an arbitrary feature to me until now, that totally makes sense lol

Answer (score 0):

In vim to move the cursor to the end of line especially with non white space use a or A